# How to solve 'numpy.float64' object has no attribute 'encode' in python 3

Tags: python, numpy, tweepy, sentiment-analysis

I am  trying to do a sentiment analysis in twitter about different car brands,i am using python 3 for this.While running the code i am getting the below exception

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Jeet Chatterjee\NLP\Maruti_Toyota_Marcedes_Brand_analysis.py", line 55, in <module>
x = str(x.encode('utf-8','ignore'),errors ='ignore')
AttributeError: 'numpy.float64' object has no attribute 'encode'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Jeet Chatterjee\NLP\Maruti_Toyota_Marcedes_Brand_analysis.py", line 62, in <module>
tweets.set_value(idx,column,'')
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 1856, in set_value
engine.set_value(series._values, index, value)
 File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 116, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.set_value (pandas\_libs\index.c:4690)
File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 130, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.set_value (pandas\_libs\index.c:4578)
File "pandas\_libs\src\util.pxd", line 101, in util.set_value_at (pandas\_libs\index.c:21043)
  File "pandas\_libs\src\util.pxd", line 93, in util.set_value_at_unsafe (pandas\_libs\index.c:20964)
 ValueError: could not convert string to float:
```

I don't how to represent the encode in python 3 . And here is my code

```
from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
from tweepy import Stream
from textblob import TextBlob
import json
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
#regular expression in python
import re

#data corpus
tweets_data_path = 'carData.txt'
tweets_data = []
tweets_file = open(tweets_data_path, "r")
for line in tweets_file:
    try:
        tweet = json.loads(line)
        tweets_data.append(tweet)
    except:
        continue
#creating panda dataset        
tweets = pd.DataFrame()
index = 0
    for num, line in enumerate(tweets_data):
  try:

     print (num,line['text'])

     tweets.loc[index,'text'] = line['text']
     index = index + 1 
  except:
         print(num, "line not parsed")
         continue

   def brand_in_tweet(brand, tweet):
       brand = brand.lower()
       tweet = tweet.lower()
       match = re.search(brand, tweet)
       if match:
        print ('Match Found')
        return brand
    else:
        print ('Match not found')
        return 'none'
for index, row in tweets.iterrows():
temp = TextBlob(row['text'])
tweets.loc[index,'sentscore'] = temp.sentiment.polarity

  for column in tweets.columns:
  for idx in tweets[column].index:
    x = tweets.get_value(idx,column)
    try:
        x = str(x.encode('utf-8','ignore'),errors ='ignore')          
        if type(x) == unicode:
            str(str(x),errors='ignore')
        else: 
            df.set_value(idx,column,x)
    except Exception:
        print ('encoding error: {0} {1}'.format(idx,column))
        tweets.set_value(idx,column,'')
        continue
tweets.to_csv('tweets_export.csv')

if __name__=='__main__':

  brand_in_tweet()
```

I have posted the full code , i am not getting any clue about this error , that how to solve this . Please help and thanks in advance .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a problem in this line:

```
 x = str(x.encode('utf-8','ignore'),errors ='ignore')
```

`x` is a `numpy.float64`. The code is trying to first encode it as utf8, then convert it to a string. But that is the wrong way around, because only strings can be encoded. First convert it to a string, then encode the string:

```
 x = str(x).encode('utf-8','ignore')
```

Comment: thanks for the answer the exception is removed i am agetting another exception NameError: name 'df' is not defined, how to solve this ?

Comment: Your code says `df.set_value(idx,column,x)` but you don't define `df` anywhere. My guess is that it is supposed to be a pandas dataframe. The only dataframe your code only defines is `tweets` so maybe that line should be `tweets.set_value(idx,column,x)`. Otherwise you need `df=pd.DataFrame()`. I can't tell you which because I don't really understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: thanks for the instant reply, your answer are very helpful, So basically what i am trying is a comparison of 3 brads of car suzuki, toyota,Marcedes , i want to compare the popularity of three brands.that carData.txt contains the tweets about those three brands, thats it.

Comment: The error message is very explicit. It tells you that in line 58 `df is not defined`. From your description you only have one dataframe. So your code should be consistently calling it `tweets` and not sometimes `tweets` (in lines 23, 48, 52, 61) and sometimes `df`(in line 58). I'm guessing that you got some sample code to work from and weren't consistent about renaming the variable.

Comment: yes, you are correct. i am new to these field and trying to grab this skill

Answer (score 1):

Question :

> TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "numpy.float64") to str

Solution:

For example: `print("Accuracy" + str(accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred)))`

use `str()` to concatenate `int64` and `string`